# Shell_exec Git pull request

Tags: php, git, github

I would like to make shell_exec who downloads all data from my github account.

But when I am trying to dump this, I get other HDD dump, but not the information what I want to get.

```
$target = shell_exec('dir C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\ibexec\\git-core\\git.exe -c git pull origin');
var_dump($target);
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem.

Comment: My question is, how can I make script, who will download all data from my github account?

Answer (score 0):

The "exes" in libexec ( which you seem to have typed wrong as well) are shortcuts to the exes in the bin folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin). Use those, and if the bin folder is already in PATH, you can just do `git pull origin` to get what you want.

Comment: And where he will download all files?